# How can i add custom fields in moodle assignment plugin?

Tags: moodle

How can i replace the "online text" editor by several custom form fields (free text, drop-down, check boxes) that the learners have to complete?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a custom assignment submission plugin https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Assign_submission_plugins (or find an existing plugin that does what you want - https://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=category&id=42 ).